# Grep a key value pair in JSON as CLI

Tags: sed, grep, jq

I have a big Datalog with JSON. One JSON element looks like this:

```
{
  "context": {
    "callback": {
      "Data": {
        "LastSessionTime": "2020-06-07T09:16:19Z",
        "TrackingEnabled": "1",
        "Language": "en"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to grep all the line containing "TrackingEnabled" : "1" and save it into another file. I also want to  I am using following command:

```
grep "TrackingEnabled" : "1" data.log > tracked.log
grep -v "TrackingEnabled" : "1" data.log > untracked.log
```

But I am getting the error:

```
grep: :: No such file or directory
grep: 1: No such file or directory
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Post more lines of your sample input. What is the output you are expecting from the input

Comment: Since the pattern contains whitespace, you need to protect it from word splitting by the shell ex. `grep '"TrackingEnabled": "1"'` . However you really should consider using a dedicated JSON tool such as `jq`.

Comment: in defence of OP JSON's got logic of its own (a bit like XML), in a hurry there is always temptation to use `grep`/`awk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) nor [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) are the right tool to parse [json](/questions/tagged/json), use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) instead:

```
jq -r '
     .context.callback.Data |
     select(.TrackingEnabled == "1") |
     "TrackingEnabled: " + .TrackingEnabled
' file.json
```

### Output

```
TrackingEnabled: 1
```

And from new requirements from comments:

```
jq -r '
    [
       .context.callback.Data |
       select(.TrackingEnabled == "1") |
       "TrackingEnabled: " + .TrackingEnabled, .LastSessionTime
    ]
' file.json
```

### Output

```
[
  "TrackingEnabled: 1",
  "2020-06-07T09:16:19Z"
]
```

Comment: Thanks, wonderful solution!
And how do I select two lines? I mean I want an output like this: [TrackingEnable: 1, 2020-06-07T09:16:19Z].

Comment: jq -r '[
     .context.callback.Data |
     select(.TrackingEnabled == "0") |
     "TrackingEnabled: " + .TrackingEnabled, .context.callback.Data. LastSessionTime]' rf_paid_callback.log > untracked.csv